# Icefaces 1.8.2 and JQuery 1.5.2

Tags: jquery, jsf, icefaces

Want to display character count for textarea. I am trying to achieve this by jquery.

I am getting this error when user types in

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (anonymous function) onkeyup
```

my jquery  snippet

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
function limitChars(textid, limit, infodiv){
var text = $j('#'+textid).val();
var textlength = text.length;
if(textlength > limit){
    $j('#' + infodiv).html('You cannot write more then '+limit+' characters!');
    $j('#'+textid).val(text.substr(0,limit));
    return false;
}
```

Please suggest what needs to be corrected

Comment: You will need to show us your html, and how you bind this method..

Answer (score 0):

try this mate:

http://jsfiddle.net/VGpgP/3/

is it possible for you to implement yours in this way?

Comment: gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
(anonymous function)
onkeyup`